# Outputting tictactoe board

Tags: python

I'm trying to print my tictactoe board so it looks like

```
 | | 
-+-+-
 | |
-+-+-
 | |
```

This is my code:

```
def __str__(self):
    result = ""
    for i in range(self.nrows):
        for j in range(self.ncols):
            cell = str(self.gameboard[i][j])
            result += cell + "|"
        result += "\n"
        result += "-+"
        result += '\n'
    return result
```

The result looks like

```
 | | |
-+
 | | |
-+
 | | |
-+
```

How should I change the code so it looks like the first board? `self.nrows` is the number of rows, `self.ncols` is the number of columns, and `self.gameboard` is the 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the most pythonic way, and you probably should diverge the code into some functions, but it's working:

```
def __str__(self):
    result = ""
    for i in range(self.nrows):
        for j in range(self.ncols-1):
            cell = str(self.gameboard[i][j])
            result += cell + "|"
        result += "\n"
        if i == self.nrows - 1:
            break  # added the last line, which is just |
        for j in range(self.ncols-1):
            result += "-+"
        result += '-'
        result += '\n'
    return result
```

Output for `self.nrows = self.ncols = 3` and `self.gameboard[i][j] = ' '` for each i,j:

```
 | |
-+-+-
 | |
-+-+-
 | |
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the row `result += "-+"` to `result += "-+" * self.ncols + "-"`. Reason is that you print `"-+"` symbol only once, but need to do that as many time as your number of columns. Also, in the end you need to add one more `"-"` symbol to make it look symmetric. In the end just remove the last row that have 2*ncols+2 symbols.

The complete code would be:

```py
def __str__(self):
    result = ""
    for i in range(self.nrows):
        for j in range(self.ncols):
            cell = str(self.gameboard[i][j])
            result += cell + "|"
        result += "\n"
        result += "-+" * self.ncols + "-"
        result += '\n'

    # Remove the last row
    result = result[:-2*ncols-2]
    result += "\n"
    return result
```